# How to validate HashMap and bind errors in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have entity Category that has attribute names which is HashMap. I can have multiple names for one category in different languages. I would like to create custom validator that rejects null values (i always set key in jsp so key is always not null) and binds them into jsp using form:errors
Here is my code so far. Problem is that when in form:error I use path names, errors shows for every input.I need to display error for every input separately.

Many thanks for answer of any kind

```
       @Entity
    public class Category extends AbstractEntity {
        @ValidMap(message = "{NotNull}")
        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @MapKeyColumn(name="language")
        @Column(name="name")
        @CollectionTable(name="category_name", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="category_id"))
        Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<>();
}
    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = ValidMapValidator.class)
    @ReportAsSingleViolation
    @Documented
    public @interface ValidMap {
        String message() default "{}";
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    }

    public class ValidMapValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMap, Map<String, String>> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ValidMap validMap) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Map<String, String> map, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            boolean isValid = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue()==null){
                    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{NotNull}")
                            .addBeanNode()
                            .inIterable().atKey( entry.getKey().toString() )
                            .addConstraintViolation();

                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save-category/{id}")
    public String saveCategory(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                               @ModelAttribute("category") @Validated Category category,
                               BindingResult result,
                               Locale locale,
                               Model model
    ) {
        if(result.hasErrors()){

            model.addAttribute("category");
            model.addAttribute("validationFailed", true);

            return "offer/category";
        }
        categoryRepo.save(category);

        return "redirect:/offers/items/" + id;
    }
```

And Jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${url}" modelAttribute="category" class="form-horizontal" id="category_form">
    <table class="table borderless">
      <c:forEach items="${category.names}" var="name" varStatus="status">
        <tr class="offer-names">
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first_name_input" class="col-sm-2 control-label label-name" style="text-align: left">
                <spring:message code="ware.name"/>
              </label>

              <div class="col-sm-2 input-name">
                <form:input path="names['${name.value} ${key = name.key}']"
                            cssStyle="width: 100%" cssClass="input-name-field" value="${name.value}"/>
                <br>
                <form:errors path="names"/>
              </div>
              <div style="margin-top: 3px; color: darkgray" id="offer_name_language_text">
                <span><spring:message code="offer.language.${name.key}"/></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <label id="radioLabel" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align: left;">
              <spring:message code="users.table.active"/>
            </label>

            <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 5px">
              <form:radiobutton path="isActive" value="true" id="active"/>
              <label for="active">
                <spring:message code="users.active.yes"/>
              </label><br>
              <form:radiobutton path="isActive" value="false" id="notActive"/>
              <label for="notActive">
                <spring:message code="users.active.no"/>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2" style="text-align: right">
              <c:url value="${backUrl}" var="backUrlVar"/>
              <a href="${backUrlVar}" class="btn btn-default">
                <spring:message code="displayOrganization.button.back"/>
              </a>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                     value="<spring:message code="editOrganization.save"/>"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <form:hidden path="offer.id" value="${id}"/>
    <c:if test="${not empty category.id}">
      <form:hidden path="id" value="${category.id}"/>
    </c:if>
  </form:form>
```